# How do I insert a variable into a dynamically loaded module's namespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

I'm trying to dynamically import a Python module at runtime, but I want the importing code to provide a missing a variable to the module that is being imported.

- The Python3 `builtins` module can achieve the behaviour I want, but I don't know if this is best practice, or the best way to do this.

Secondarily, I would like the file-to-be-imported to tell the importing code which variables need to be provided. I have 2 potential solutions:

- I can just run `exec_module`, catch the name errors, parse out the missing variable, add this to the builtins and rerun exec_module till it succeeds.
- Otherwise I was thinking of providing some annotation in `file_to_import.py` like `# VARIABLES var1 var2 var3`, then reading the first line from the file (and parsing this annotation) before the `exec_module`.

Essentially what I have is:

**file_to_import.py:**

```py
# Potentially: VARIABLES my_inserted_variable
print(my_inserted_variable)
```

**file_that_does_the_import.py**

```py
# `values` is some dictionary of values I could provide
complete, stored_attributes = False, set()
while not complete:
    try:
        spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
        complete = True
    except NameError as e:
        name = str(e).split("'")[1]
        if name not in values:
            raise e

        setattr(builtins, name, values.get(name))
        stored_attributes.add(name)

for k in stored_attributes:
    delattr(builtins, k)
```

Just wondering if `builtins` is the best way to accomplish passing data from the importing code to an imported module.